# How to make requirejs shimmed module able to access a dependency not defined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs

```
require.config({
            shim:{
                "openLayers": {
                    deps: ["proj4", "css!/libs/ol3/v3.11.2/ol.css"],
                },
                "jsts": {
                 //   exports:"jsts",
                    deps: ["libs/jsts/javascript.util.min", "openLayers"]
                }
            }
}
```

my problem is that the jsts library expects the "openLayers" dependency to be defined in the code.

Is it possible to somehow configure this in requirejs or will I have to wrap the jsts library with amd define calls?

Is there a grunt task that can do the following wrapping if needed?

```
define(["openLayers"], function (ol) {
    //jsts code
});
```

Comment: "my problem is that the jsts library expects the "openLayers" dependency to be defined in the code." What does this actually mean?

Comment: That the library is depending on the ol variable to be defined to function. ect that the developer has loading openlayers javascritp files before loading jsts. The solution wraps the jsts code ith thedefine call that allows it to load ol first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a grunt task:

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-umd');
 umd: {
            jsts: {
                options: {
                    src: 'wwwroot/libs/jsts/jsts.min.js',
                    dest: 'wwwroot/libs/jsts/jsts.umd.min.js', 
                    objectToExport: 'jsts',
                    amdModuleId: 'jsts',                     
                    deps: { 
                        'default': ['ol'],
                         amd: ['openLayers'],
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```